# What is the probability of this Rubik's cube configuration?

Tags: rubiks-cube

What percentage of the total number of combinations on a Rubik's Cube have the following property:

> On every face, no two adjacent squares have the same color.

By adjacent I mean:

> adjacent: sharing a common side.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of the exact answer.  There are 72 pairs of adjacent squares, so perhaps it would be near $(5/6)^{72}$ or around 2 in a million.

Comment: It can't be that low. I almost randomly hit on a combination just like that, after making something like 10 or 15 moves. It just can't be 2 in a million

Comment: Another argument: Each edge may be in 17 of the 24 positions to avoid matching a centre cubie. $(17/24)^{12}=0.016$.  The chance the eight corners in any particular arrangement cause no clash would be $(4/6)^{24}$, or maybe $(4/6)^{20}(5/6)^4=0.000145$.  The product is 2.3 millionths.

Comment: @Truth-seek were your moves uniformly random?  I'm guessing maybe you preferred moves that broke up adjacent colors (as I would do if trying to intentionally scramble the puzzle).  In that case you'd naturally get to a configuration with the given property pretty quickly; that doesn't sound incompatible with there being 2 in a million of them.